# Wordpress Custom post inquire

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am making a system in WordPress that using the custom post that is fine and working.

But I am stuck here problem is that my eacy custom post has various prices and these prices are add to database on daily basis.

May I create the post meta ? 
Or create new price rate table in database ?

My only concern with price rate update and insertion on daily basis.

As far as my experience post meta data will not concern here ?

If I create new table so I am afraid about the `wp_query` might be I have no change to fetch the data from new design table though `wp_query`.

any guy guide me right way ?

Comment: How you plan to update prices data daily? If it is some custom plugin which will be taking care of daily price updates.. you can run loop for each concerned post and  update_post_meta for the price meta key.. or you see issues with it? Also if you went with custom table, you can use custom $wpdb class to pull records from custom table and display in your templates.

Comment: I don not like the wp_postmeta db table structure for holdup large volume of data against each post. do you recommended this ?

Comment: I have a excel file to update the prices

Comment: You are right we should not use large volume of data in meta, but price for each product should not be large data, and meta seems like good option to save the number... for info like pricing yes meta should be just fine. However as you need to bulk update prices and each price gonna be different for each product, so maybe you need something robust to update it at onces, and meta interface might be time consuming if you do not automate it via php to update all posts and meta via some loop...

Comment: I want to store the prices also in db

Comment: no update exiting meta data against any post I want to insert the prices on regular basis and I also need the yesterdays and last prices also for keep record in database.